# Pinging Android devices from C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, .net

I'm trying to make a program witch will automatically discover an Android device (Galaxy S2 running Android 4.2) and start communicating with it.

The idea is to send a packet to all the devices connected on the local network (between 2 and 6 devices at most) and the one who answers the request is the one I'm looking for.
First I'm pinging all the possible local IP addressees and send the packet to the successful pings.

I have ran into a problem when pinging the device from C#. I have no problem pinging it the normal way through the command line, but doing that with code works maybe 30% of the time, the rest of the time I get an 11050 reply (witch I haven't bees successful in deciphering)

This is my ping code:

```
    public static bool PingIt(string IP)
    {
        // Get an object that will block the main thread.
        AutoResetEvent waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Ping pingSender = new Ping();
        PingOptions options = new PingOptions();
        // Use the default Ttl value which is 128, 
        // but change the fragmentation behavior. 
        options.DontFragment = true;
        options.Ttl = 128;

        // When the PingCompleted event is raised,
        // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
        pingSender.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

        // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted. 
        string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        int timeout = 5000;
        //PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(IP, timeout, buffer, options);

        try
        {
            pingSender.SendAsync(IP, timeout, buffer, options, waiter);
            //pingSender.SendAsync(IP, timeout, IP);
        }
        catch (PingException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And the callback:

```
    private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user.
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");
            // Let the main thread resume. 
            // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread 
            // is waiting for.
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }
        // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user.
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());
            // Let the main thread resume. 
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        PingReply reply = e.Reply;
        Console.WriteLine(reply.Address.ToString() + " " + reply.Status.ToString());

        // Let the main thread resume.
        ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();

        lock(lockObj)
        {
            pingProgress++;

            //if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                //availableDevices.Add(reply.Address.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The output is just the result from the pings. I have tried turning the firewall off too, but it doesn't help. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you heard of Google Cloud Messaging for Android? http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately, that GCM is not going to help me all that much, being a notification service.
All I need is a simple way to get the IP address of the device.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, so I'm guessing you've found a solution or a workaround since then, but here are a couple of suggestions anyway.

I think there is an error in your logic. You set up an AutoResetEvent to wait on, and you use SendAsync, which is a non-blocking call, but you never wait on the AutoResetEvent, so your program just goes on and does other things. In the callback there is a comment "Let the main thread resume." and you Set the AutoResetEvent, but nobody is waiting on it, right?

Next, the idea of "pinging all the possible local IP addressees" sounds like a poor idea. Network administrators will not feel kindly towards you.

My suggestion (which may not be feasible, not knowing exactly what your setup is) is that your Android app should send a little "hello, I'm alive (and here is my IP address)" message to your PC program once in a while. (Not too often, to avoid battery drain.) And your PC program should keep track of the last 10 IP addresses for the Android devices who have said hello.